# Set-up and deploy browserify build (dist) with git, npm (browserify/watchify) and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, npm, browserify, package.json

I am working on a redux app (let's call it `Client`) packaged with browserify and I am now looking at deploying it.

- While coding, am I using `watchify` to continuously watch changes and rebuild the application; Of course the output isn't minified and include debug and source map in the javascript bundled file.
- Because of that, my `/dist/js/client.js` was, until now, included in my `.gitignore` file, but not in `.npmignore` since `/dist/*` needs to be in the final package.

`Client` is a npm package being use in another (`rails`) app that relies on the the final javascript build. Whenever I deploy my `rails` app it will run `npm install`, fetch `client`, and use its build.

Two options :

- 1) a `postinstall` script on `client`, actually running `npm run build`

  - Pro: It would be great, and avoid committing the build
  - Con: Requires browserify, babel, node-sass etc, which are `devDependencies` and therefore not included in the final `production` environment (`build` fails, and I don't want to add those package as `dependency`, it doesn't make sense to me.
- 2) actually committing the build together with the client

  - Pro: It works
  - Con: This is pretty annoying since whenever in dev mode, running watchify, the build file is being replaced, which might result in inadvertently committing an unminified dev version of `Client` and is also really annoying from the git perspective (there's always uncommitted change to the branch, it's creating conflicts with other developers etc).
  - I tried to `.gitignore` the file and `git add --force` it at the same time,  so that I could have a manual `publish` script, but git doesn't seem to like it.

What is the proper approach to this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Right now I use 
`npm run release` locally,
which is running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
git stash 
git fetch
git checkout -b "release/$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)"
git pull origin master
npm run build
git add :/dist/* --force
git commit -m '[NPM] (publish) Commiting build'
git push origin HEAD
git rm --cached :/dist/js/*.js
git rm --cached :/dist/css/*.css
git checkout @{-1}
git stash pop
```

But I really don't like it :-)